# symbols displayed at run time but not present in code

Tags: php, html

I am creating a site with html and php.
When I Run my php page on borwser using localhost(XAMPP server), then some symbols (ï»¿) are displayed but when I check my html-php code, then no symbol or script like: `&iquest; or &raquo;` is found.

If i am wrong somewhere then Please let me know.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: Most definitely a BOM issue.

Comment: its a 370 line code even more than that... is there any way to find that code or script out?

Comment: please let me know how can I resolve the BOM issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a [UTF-8 byte-order marker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8). You should configure your editor to save UTF-8 *without* BOM. It isn't mandatory for the UTF-8 encoding; in fact, its use is discouraged and it only causes problems.

Additionally, make sure your web server is sending an appropriate Content-Type HTTP header:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

`&iquest;` or `&raquo;` are html entities, they are looks different at php code and at browser. You can find them, for example, [here](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/web/codehtml.html). Also, you possibly have an issue with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Answer (score 0):

My best guess: You have an issue with encoding (UTF vs. ISO). Look up encoding used by your editor on saving, and send it to the browser like i.e. `header("Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8")`

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you're dealing with a character encoding problem.
try to declare the encoding in your headers.

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8")
```

this needs to be output before any text is sent to the client.